# AngularJS use factory to calculate changes to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make a simple pay calculator so that you have a list of staff and their current rate and hours and you can manipulate the rate and the hours to work out which staff will cost the most.

I have the below which is contained in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPeNYO).

I am trying to keep all my logic in the factory however event though I know the staff model is being updated I am not able to update the pay model via this method.

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
          <table>
            <tr><td>name</td><td>rate</td><td>hours</td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="s in staff">
                <td>{{s.name}}</td>
                <td><input ng-keyup="keyPress(s.rate)" ng-model="s.rate"></td>  
                <td><input ng-keyup="keyPress(s.hours)" ng-model="s.hours"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
          <table>
            <tr><td>name</td><td>pay</td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="b in CalcPay">
                <td>{{b.1.name}}</td>
                <td>{{b.1.pay}}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>          
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('staffFactory', function ($http, $compile, $rootScope, $controller) {
    var staff = [
        {"id": "1","name": "Kate","rate": "10", "hours": "10"},
        {"id": "2","name": "John","rate": "20", "hours": "10"},
        {"id": "3","name": "Matt","rate": "15", "hours": "10"}
    ];

    var unique = {},
        distinct = [];
    for (var i in staff) {
        if (typeof (unique[staff[i].id]) == "undefined")  {
            distinct.push(staff[i].id);
        }
        unique[staff[i].id] = unique[staff[i].id] || {pay:0};
        unique[staff[i].id].name = staff[i].name;
        unique[staff[i].id].pay += (parseInt(staff[i].rate, 10) * parseInt(staff[i].hours, 10));
    }

    var pay = [];
    for (var p in unique) {
        pay.push([p, unique[p]]);
        pay.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (b[1].pay - a[1].pay);
        });
    }

    var staffService = {};
    staffService.allStaff = function () {
        return staff;
    };

    staffService.CalcPay = function () {
        return pay;
    };

    return staffService;
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'staffFactory', function ($scope, staffFactory) {
    $scope.staff = staffFactory.allStaff();
    $scope.CalcPay = staffFactory.CalcPay();
    $scope.keyPress = function(keyCode){
        console.log($scope.staff);
        $scope.CalcPay = staffFactory.CalcPay();
    };    
}]);
</script>
```

I have this working when I put my CalcPay into the controller (see below) or this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNMgVK).

Everything I read seems to suggest this is not best practice and slows the app down, so I am looking to find a way to get this done without relying on the function in my controller?

How can this be acheived?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'staffFactory', function ($scope, staffFactory) {
    $scope.staff = staffFactory.allStaff();
  function CalcPay () {
      var unique = {},
        distinct = [];
    for (var i in $scope.staff) {
        if (typeof (unique[$scope.staff[i].id]) == "undefined")  {
            distinct.push($scope.staff[i].id);
        }
        unique[$scope.staff[i].id] = unique[$scope.staff[i].id] || {pay:0};
        unique[$scope.staff[i].id].name = $scope.staff[i].name;
        unique[$scope.staff[i].id].pay += (parseInt($scope.staff[i].rate, 10) * parseInt($scope.staff[i].hours, 10));
    }

    var pay = [];
    for (var p in unique) {
        pay.push([p, unique[p]]);
        pay.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (b[1].pay - a[1].pay);
        });
    }
  return pay;
  };
    $scope.CalcPay = CalcPay();
    $scope.keyPress = function(keyCode){
        $scope.CalcPay = CalcPay();
    };    
}]);
```

Comment: Yes, it is not right practice to keep your business type logic inside controller. I am not sure, are you trying to achieve your result using factory method approach? And using second code snippet(i.e, logic inside controller) you are getting desired result. Right?

Comment: @Vaibhav yes I am getting the desired result here  (second bit of code) however I want to improve my code so that I don't run into performance issues down the track on a larger project.

Comment: If you keep your logic in factory, then it gets created as singleton instance, so same instance can be used in other controllers, and it makes writing test cases easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are calling CalcPay method of factory, that method is just returning a value `pay` . You are not calculating anything as you are doing in another code snippet where you are calculating everything in controller. SO instead of returning just pay, either right all logic of calculation inside CalcPay or keep all logic inside some other function and call that from CalcPay.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('staffFactory', function ($http, $compile, $rootScope, $controller) {
    var staff = [
        {"id": "1","name": "Kate","rate": "10", "hours": "10"},
        {"id": "2","name": "John","rate": "20", "hours": "10"},
        {"id": "3","name": "Matt","rate": "15", "hours": "10"}
    ];

    function calcPayInner(){
    var unique = {},
        distinct = [],pay = [];
    for (var i in staff) {
        if (typeof (unique[staff[i].id]) == "undefined")  {
            distinct.push(staff[i].id);
        }
        unique[staff[i].id] = unique[staff[i].id] || {pay:0};
        unique[staff[i].id].name = staff[i].name;
        unique[staff[i].id].pay += (parseInt(staff[i].rate, 10) * parseInt(staff[i].hours, 10));
    }

        for (var p in unique) {
        pay.push([p, unique[p]]);
        pay.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (b[1].pay - a[1].pay);
        });
    }
    }
    var staffService = {};
    staffService.allStaff = function () {
        return staff;
    };

    staffService.CalcPay = function () {
        return calcPayInner();
    };

    return staffService;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, this helps my understanding as well! To get your calcPayInner function working I had to return pay at the end of it as well.